# Android Release APK Error while updating property 'focusable' of a view managed by: RNSVGSvgView

Tags: android, react-native, logcat

I build an app using react-native, it works fine, but when I build a release APK file and I installed it in a real device, I got this error

```
AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'focusable' of a view managed by: RNSVGSvgView
```

My app use FontAwesome and this is a part of `package.json` file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.4.1",
    "react-native-sha256": "1.3.6",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "4.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.24",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.11.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.4.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "3.13.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "11.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "9.9.4",
    "react-native-table-component": "1.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "2.5.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: is that due to SVG or map?

Comment: I use FontAwesome so it's SVG

Comment: Can you post your error screenshot along with package json?

Comment: I edit this post with `package.json` file